# how to write correctly - js in html in return statement

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a return statement in JSX. I need to delete the first element of the array and return the reduced array and then map it. But the app crashes on the line of reducing array.

I checked - this is an  array. So I suppose this is about that I write JSX incorrectly.
Please, could you help me.

```
return (
    <div className="popup__toggle">
    {let newArr = event.slice(1)}                                                                                   
    {console.log(newArr)}                                                              
    {newArr.map((item, index) => {                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        return(                                                                                                         
            <div>{item.name}</div>                                                                                                      
        )
    )}
</div>
```

I need to delete the first index of the array and map it.

Answer (score 1):

**Notice 1:**

You are handling JSX as a raw JS problem. You need to do it with functional solutions. So instead of defining variables using `let` you can slice the variable directly and then use the result.

So your code would be like below:

```js
return (
    <div className="popup__toggle">                                                       
    {event.slice(1).map(item => {
        return(                                                                                                         
            <div>{item.name}</div>                                                                                                      
        )
    })}

</div>
)
```

**Notice 2:**

You didn't close your brace correctly. I mean the one in the map item. You haven't closed it. instead of that I recommend to return your result without `brace` and `return`. Like below:

```
{event.slice(1).map(item => item)}
```

This is as an abbreviation for that. So your could could be like below:

```
{event.slice(1).map(item => {
    return <div>{item.name}</div>
})}
```

Or

```
{event.slice(1).map(item => <div>{item.name}</div>)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return (
      <div className="popup__toggle">
        {event.slice(1).map(item => <div key={item.name}>{item.name}</div>)}                                                                                                                                                                                   
      </div>
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it right, but, instead of having your `newArr` var inside `JSX`, which exactly what you mentioned, do it outside your return function:

> So I suppose this is about that I write JSX incorrectly.

Do this

```
render(){
  let newArr = event ? event.slice(1) : []; //the new place for the new array. also added a check [event &&] to check if the array is there or not. if its not there it will return an empty array to prevent rendering issues due to newArr.map().
  return (
    <div className="popup__toggle">
      {
        newArr.map((item, index) => <div key={`item.name-#${index + 1}`}>{item.name}</div>)
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```